# Fbx color not display in 3 js editor

Tags: three.js, 3d

I need to see my 3D Objects in Viewer. Only i need to use 3 Js Editor.

I was shared my  FBX File,this file original color is green but not preview Correctly.  I don't know which property i need to change.

Can you please help me what is the problem is there?

This is original 3D file viewed in Blender.

[image]

But in Three Js Editor Showing Like this :

[image]

This is Link for Online 3 Js Editor => https://threejs.org/editor/

**Sample File :**

https://free3d.com/3d-model/android_icon_3d-13483.html

Comment: I am also have this doubt. Any one help us.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the model does not have color- or material information in the FBX-file. Try opening the FBX in blender and you see it rendered with default-material. Apparently only the .blend-version has color-information stored.

On the detail-page it also says "Materials: No".

You can try to re-export it from blender including material-information in another format.

Answer (score 0):

You can add Directional Light to the scene and then the colors will be visible.